# Customize OAuth authentication in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I'm currently in the process of implementing an OAuth2 authentication into a Spring Boot application (using the latest Spring Boot Version 2.0.1). I followed the tutorial from http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2018/03/spring-boot-2-native-approach-to-sso.html which already put me into the lucky position where the  authentication itself is up and running.

However after the authentication using OAuth2 (I'm using Google as authentication provider for now) I would like to enhance the `Principal`(or any other object accessible to the application) with additional data.

The basic usecase is like this:

1. Perform OAuth2 authorization.
2. Check the user infomation returned from the OAuth provider.
3. If a user with the matching ID from the OAuth provider can be found in a local database then enhance the `Principal`with that user information and proceed.
4. If a user with the matching ID from the Oauth provider can **not** be found in the local database then show an error message and block the login.

Step 1 Is working fine but I cannot find any way to add a listener, an interceptor or any other kind of configurative element into the default Spring processing that would allow me to do steps 2-4.

I already looked into the multiple configuration options inside the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and several other source, so far without success. The closest thing I found online was using a `PrincipalExtractor` but that doesn't seem to be supported any more since Spring Boot 2.

Any idea of how I can perform the interception and inject my additional logics?

Comment: Did you read [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-userinfo-endpoint)? There are the solutions of all your problems.

Comment: Damn... the most obvious solution and I didn't take a look. Thanks @dur!